# Commutative rings with many nilpotent elements and efficient computation

Tags: nt.number-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $K$ be commutative ring. Assume that for natural $n$
there are $n$ nilpotent elements $y_i \in K$ satisfying 
$y_i^2=0, y_i y_j=y_j y_i \ne 0$ and $\prod_1^ny_i \neq 0$.

Is it possible to compute in time $\exp o(n)$:
$$
f=\prod_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{j=1}^na_{i,j}y_j\right).
$$
for $a_{i,j} \in K$?

Very likely the answer is negative because of @Aaron's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328021/finding-coefficient-of-multivariate-polynomial).

Treating $y_i$ as variables $f$ is homogeneous and is a single monomial.

Example with many nilpotent elements, but inefficient computation
is $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots x_n]/(x_1^2,x_2^2\ldots x_n^2)$

Comment: You would also want $\prod_1^ny_i \neq 0.$

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz Indeed, thanks. I edited.

Comment: How does Aaron's answer to the other question not settle this up to Valiant's perm vs. det conjecture?