# Counting Hamiltonian cycles in graph and finding a coefficient of polynomial

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, polynomials, additive-combinatorics

Exact result is #P-Hard, so we are looking for bounds.

Let $G$ be simple graph or simple digraph and $A$ its
adjacency matrix. $A$ is $n \times n$ with entries only zeros or ones.

Let $K=\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,\ldots x_n]$.

Define the Hamiltonian matrix of $G$ to be the matrix $M$
over $K$ with entries row $i$ of $A$ multiplied by $x_i$:
$M_{1 \le i,j\le n}=x_i A_{i,j}$.

Let $f(x_1,...x_n)=(M^n)_{1,1}$.

If you prefer take $f_2=\frac1n \mathrm{tr}(M^n)$.

$f,f_2$ are homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$ and all the coefficients
are nonnegative, so there is no cancellation.

$f,f_2$ are prohibitively large to be computed as sums of monomial,
but it has succinct representation as arithmetic circuit.
In addition CAS can compute it over other domains, including
finite fields and possibly setting some of the variables
to constants.

Let $H(G)$ the coefficient of $x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdots x_n$ in $f$
(or in $f_2$)

$H(G)$ counts the number of directed Hamiltonian cycles in $G$,
if $G$ is undirected it is twice the number of undirected cycles.

Except for the monomial of $H(G)$, all other monomials are divisible
by square.

If we could work efficiently in $K/[x_1^2,x_2^2...,x_n^2]$
$H$ will be the coefficient of the only remaining monomial,
but many commuting nilpotent elements with efficient computations
don't appear to exists.

Another approach, disproved by @Peter Taylor is to convert
the multivariate case to univariate by setting $x_i= y^{g(i)}$
for some function $g(i)$.

It is tempting to try to use some case of "distinguished"
property like purely real over the complex numbers.

> Q1 What properties and bound can we get about $H(G)$ in subexponential
> in $n$ time and space?

Observe that this need not contradict Exponential Time Hypotheses (ETH)
since the reduction SAT to Hamiltonian cycle need not be linear.

To clarify about subexponential comment. Assume $G$ is planar graph.
Then the Treewidth of $G$ is $O(\sqrt{n})$ and Hamiltonian
cycle ($H(G)>0$) can be solved in $O(\exp{\sqrt{n}})$.
To our knowledge this doesn't contradict widely believed conjectures,
it implies that there is no $o(n^2)$ reduction from SAT
to HC in planar graph.

One very crude upper bound on $H(G)$ is setting $x_i=1$ and then
take the integer result.

Comment: Testing for a Hamiltonian cycle is NP-complete, so even being able to test whether $H(G) > 0$ in sub-exponential time would be surprising. Are you just looking for upper bounds?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I edited with example.

Comment: Taking $f = \frac1n \mathrm{tr}(M^n)$ would be a more symmetric choice.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Thanks, probably will edit. For undirected graphs both count **twice** the cycle, right? (it is consistent with your pari/gp code)

Comment: @joro: yes, they count *directed* cycles. You may also like to check https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01396 for the formulas behind PARI/GP code and related questions.

Comment: The only way to choose $n$ elements allowing repetition from $\{1,2,2^2,\ldots,2^{n-1}\}$ so that their sum is $2^n-1$ is to choose one of each. So if you replace $x_i$ by $x^{2^{i-1}}$ for each $i$, then $H(G)$ is the coefficient of $x^{2^n-1}$. This is probably not a good idea due to the exponentially high powers and the loss of symmetry, but it shows that a 1-dimensional formulation exists.

Comment: The term $x_1\cdots x_n$ in $f$ is the only one with all powers odd, so the term $x_1^2\cdots x_n^2$ in $x_1\cdots x_n\,f$ is the only one with all powers even. So sum each variable in  $x_1\cdots x_n\,f$ over $\pm 1$ and you will get $2^n$ times the number of hamcycles.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay, when joro says that I "disproved... convert[ing] the multivariate case to univariate" I think it's a reference to https://mathoverflow.net/a/428266/46140 , such that the conversion requires exponentially high powers and hence exponential space and time. Similarly, summing each variable in $x_1 \cdots x_n$ over $\pm 1$ takes exponentially many evaluations. An alternative approach with exponentially many evaluations would be to do inclusion-exclusion of closed paths by summing each variable over $\{0, 1\}$.

Comment: Computing the coefficient of $x_1\cdots x_n$ was discussed in the previous question by @joro: https://mathoverflow.net/q/328021

Comment: Yes another alternative approach is computing the $n$-th term of the generating function for $\big(\frac1k\mathrm{tr}(M^k)\big)_{k\geq 0}$: $$-\log (z^n g(z^{-1})),$$ where $g(z)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $M$.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for giving the link, feel free to edit the question. Some observations: H(G) is invariant under swapping rows because of symmetry. Also for integer $a$, $f(a,1,1...1) \mod a^2$ gives sum of coefficients modulo a^2, for which the first variable occurs with exponent one in the monomials.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Thanks for giving the link, feel free to edit the question. Some observations: H(G) is invariant under swapping rows because of symmetry. Also for integer $a$, $f(a,1,1...1) \mod a^2$ gives sum of coefficients modulo a^2, for which the first variable occurs with exponent one in the monomials.